# Current debates in Earth Science?

Tags: landscape

What are the current research areas of Earth Science in which there is no absolute consensus of agreement on something?

For example:

What is the current status of the Raymo & Ruddiman hypothesis that the uplift of the Tibetan Plateau during the Cenozoic cooled the Earth, initiating the Quaternary?

If you could suggest areas where there are debates involving different schools of thought which have comparable "strength" to their arguments, that would be great.

Kind regards

Comment: I think it's an interesting question, that may seem too broad, but I cannot see how it could be more focused. The broadness is inherent to the nature of the question itself...

Comment: Hi SuziChan, welcome to Earth Science Stack Exchange.  Unfortunately, your question, which is interesting, is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange type of Q&A.  We are mostly looking for questions that can have a single answer; your question could have very many possible answers.  Perhaps there are other places where this question can be better received.

Comment: There might be one here somewhere: [Where did the continents come from?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/19261/6031)